# Why doesn't Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade Libreoffice,as Firefox?

Tags: upgrade, firefox, libreoffice

I use Ubuntu 12.04 in a machine for working,and don't know why Libreoffice doesn't upgrade to last version,and Firefox does.

Comment: Did you install libreoffice using the ppa?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's the opposite. Ubuntu is a stable system, meaning that we don't get big version upgrades for software.

The goal was to *not* keep upgrading Firefox. But Mozilla shortened its support so that it became impossible for Ubuntu to support older versions. That's why Firefox gets new versions even though the system is stable.

LibreOffice is supportable, so it doesn't get upgraded. However, in Ubuntu, you don't have to use new versions in order to get fixes, like in other systems. Bugs and security issues that are usually only available in new versions, are "backported" in Ubuntu, meaning that you can fix problems without changing versions.